# how to extract info in XML from python into list

Tags: python, xml, file, dictionary, parsing

I need to extract a patent document that is an XML file with PYTHON and output it into an adjacency list.

```
file = open('abc.txt', mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(',')
    line = [i.strip() for i in line]
```

I have tried this but it does not seem right

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour. It would be great if you post an input and the expected output.

Comment: Your question talks about XML and code speaks about abc.txt. Be confirm what you are doing and asking.